# SuiteCommerce Advanced Website: Allowing more than 1 user to register with the same email address

Tags: netsuite, suitecommerce

Our  SCA Mont Blanc webstore is currently allowing users to register using an email address that is already used by another account.

Is this standard SCA behaviour to allow this? Or have we broken something in the code or website record to allow this to occur?

An example is; someone has registered in the webstore but not purchased (so they are a lead). Another person registers using the same email address. The webstore allows this and creates another user with the same email address. How can we stop this happening? Ie Disallow duplicate emails?

Answer (score 0):

There is a module that is called Duplicate Customer Management that prevent that from happening. You need to ask a bundle provisioning for that from commerce suitesolution team.

Answer (score 0):

Our SiteBuilder webstore does the same thing.  Judging by the following, it could be by design and linked to the behavior of the Customer Center.  As long as they have different passwords, the users can both happily log in until one forgets their password and resets it using the 'Forgot Password' link.  Then only the first has access.

From SuiteAnswers ID 21353:

> ## Behavior of customers with same email address with access to the Customer Center Published 02/27/2012 04:46 PM | Updated 11/25/2016
>
> 02:05 PM | Answer Id: 21353 Customers with different passwords, even
> if they have the same email address, should be able to login to their
> specific customer centers.
>
> Ex.  1st customer - customer@email.com - password 1 - logs into
> customer center 1 2nd customer - customer@email.com - password 2 -
> logs into customer center 2
>
> In the event that customers have both email address with the same
> passwords, they would see all the roles assigned to the said email
> address.
>
> Ex.1st and 2nd customer - customer@email.com - password 1

Answer (score 0):

> **Update 10/2/2017**

As of 2017.2 the's a new feature, Duplicate Email Detection, that prevents web store shoppers from creating duplicate customer accounts.

To enable this feature:

1. Go to Setup > Company > Enable Features.
2. On the Web Presence subtab, check the box next to Web Site Duplicate
   Email Management.
3. Agree to the terms of service.
4. Click Save.
5. Go to Setup > Company > General Preferences.
6. Under Web Site Duplicate Email Management, select Enable Duplicate
   Detection.
7. Click Save.